# core data search in many-to-many relation

Tags: ios, search, core-data, nspredicate

I am new at Core data and I have some trouble whit my search.

My data structure look like this :

```
Server   --one-to-many-->   Category   --many-to-many-->   Cube
```

My idea is to get server object, grab server.category set and draw its cubes.

Now I need searching in this model. I would like to search by cube name and get :

Server object whit categories that contain come cube whit this name (or that name contain this word).

I was trying like this :

```
NSPredicate * defaultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.defaultFlag = %@ AND ANY SELF.category.cube.title = %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], text];
```

but it get me an

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'multiple to-many keys not allowed here'
```

How to do this right.

EDIT :

If I have for example : 
One server DemoServer whit 3 Category (Category1, Category2, Category3) and those category has each 3 cubes (Test , cube11, cube12), (cube21, cube22, cube23), (Test, Cube32, Test)

And I search for : Test (cube title) I would like to get

DemoServer whit 2 Categories (Category1, Category3) and those would have cubes (Test), (Test, Test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates with nested to-many relationships are a bit complicated.
 The "obvious" predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY category.cube.title = %@", text]
```

does not work if both "category" and "cube" are to-many relationships.

What you need is a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(category, $cat, ANY $cat.cube.title = %@).@count > 0", text]
```

Combined with your other predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"defaultFlag = %@ AND SUBQUERY(category, $cat, ANY $cat.cube.title = %@).@count > 0",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], text]
```

Comment: @MarkoZadravec: It is like a local variable of the SUBQUERY. `$cat` is set to each of the related category elements in turn. (Unfortunately, SUBQUERY is almost undocumented, so the question is not stupid at all :-)

Comment: Thanks, but two more problems. Now it doesn't crash but found no rows at all, the second problem is that this is not working whit ANY SELF.defaultFlag = %@ AND in front of SUBQUERY

Comment: @MarkoZadravec: What is `defaultFlag`? Is it an attribute of Server? Why is ANY used here?

Comment: Yes defaultFlag is attribute of Server. I think ANY is necessary so I would query all server whit defaultFlag == 1.

Comment: Allso my query look like 'SELECT DISTINCT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDEFAULTFLAG, t0.ZHOST, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPASSWORD, t0.ZPORT, t0.ZPROTOCOL, t0.ZSERVERID, t0.ZTOKEN, t0.ZUSERNAME FROM ZSERVER t0 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_PK) FROM ZCATEGORY t1 JOIN Z_1CUBE t2 ON t1.Z_PK = t2.Z_1CATEGORY JOIN ZCUBE t3 ON t2.Z_2CUBE = t3.Z_PK WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.ZSERVER AND ( t3.ZTITLE = ?)) ) > ? '

Comment: @MarkoZadravec: "ANY SELF.defaultFlag" is wrong (the predicate is applied to each object in the database separately), see my updated answer. - The second (SUBQUERY) part should find all servers that have at least one category which has at least one cube with the given title. It is strange that it finds no rows at all for you, I cannot explain that.

Comment: Thanks SELF.defaultFlag is now working but I still haven't got any rows yet. Am I understand this correct, Whit this query I should get all Servers whit only those categories that have at least one cube whit that name and only those cubes ? one more question, what is more time consuming doing search in code data or in array (look through array and remove those that are not relavant)?

Comment: @MarkoZadravec: As I said, the query gets all servers which have at least one category that is related to at least one cube with that name. Is that what you need? - Usually filtering in the Core Data fetch request is faster, because that is done on the SQLite level. If you filter the arrays then you have to fetch all objects and all related objects first. But it depends. If you already have everything in memory, then filtering the array would be faster. So no definitive answer!

Comment: I am not shore if this is what I want. I edit my question, pleas look at it. Thanks for your time

Comment: @MarkoZadravec: That is not possible with a fetch request. The fetch request returns a list of servers. The predicate is *only* used to filter *which* servers are returned. But a fetch request never returns "modified" objects, such as servers with only *some* categories. That's definitely impossible. - (Perhaps you can work the other way around: fetch the cubes, and then get the related categories and servers?)